# Let A be a nilpotent matrix of second degree prove $A(I \pm A)^n = A$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

$A(I \pm  A)^n = A$

let A be a nilpotent  matrix of second-degree.hence $A =[a_{ij}]$  and $I=[i_{ij}]$ then lets prove by cases:

case 1:

$$A(I + A)^n$$
$$a_{ij}(i_{ij}+a_{ij})^n$$
$$a_{ij} (\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}+1 & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}+1 
\end{bmatrix})^n$$

but I dont know what to do next??

using Hint:

$$A(I+A)^n = A[I^2+2IA+A^2] =A[I+2A] = [A+0] =A$$

Comment: Hint: Use the binomial formula to expand $A(I+A)^n$, what happens when you use the condition $A^2=I$?

Comment: @Tulip ... $A^2=0$

Comment: @Tulip Is my edit correct?

Comment: If you're not comfortable with the binomial theorem, you might use induction.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I would like to see both

Comment: @BrianMoehring You are right, my bad. It should be $A^2=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is nilpotent of degree $2$, then $A^2=0$. If you keep multiplying by $A$, you'd find that $0=A^3=A^4=\dots$. Which can be written as $$A^k=0,\qquad \forall k\ge 2$$

Now, if you use the binomial theorem ($I$ and $A$ commute), you get:
$$(I+A)^n= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} A^k$$
All the terms except the first two ($k=0$ and $k=1$) are zero, so you are left with
$$(I+A)^n=I+nA$$
Multiply both sides by $A$ to finish. The same thing applies to $(I-A)^n$ with small differences.

---

### Using induction:

Assume $A(I+A)^n=A$ for some integer $n$, multiply both sides by $(I+A)$:
$$A(I+A)^{n+1}= A(I+A)=A+A^2=A.$$
It remains to check the base case $n=1$, which should be straightforward.

Comment: $(I\pm A)^n=I\pm nA.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc you're right, edited.